# how to solve an network image

Tags: flutter, dart

**this said an error to bring the image**
it's been a short term but i have considering that it saying error and i can't get that solution.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());


    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Imagenetwork('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image widget looks kinda strange. Try something like this:

```
body: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
```

Answer (score 0):

for working with images on the net I personally like to use this variant since you can save the image in cache.
use these packages

cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
flutter_cache_manager: ^3.2.0

```
static final customCacheManager = CacheManager(Config('customCacheKey',
      stalePeriod: Duration(days: 15), maxNrOfCacheObjects: 100));
                CachedNetworkImage(
                  cacheManager: customCacheManager,
                  height: 40,
                  width: 40,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  imageUrl: imagenUrl,
                  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
                    backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF02204c),
                  ),
                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Center(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/imagenError.png',
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```